# how to set local deploy credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am getting started with cloud run and I have started with the Intellij cloud run plugin.  I can't figure out how to pass or set credentials for a local deploy in local Docker for Windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your local environment, I don't recommend to use service account key file. use your user credential that you can initialize with [gcloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install): `gcloud init`

So, to test your container locally, I [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-google-cloud-user-credentials-when-testing-containers-locally-acb57cd4e4da) on that. I'm more linux environment centric and I don't know if it will work exactly on WindowsOS. but you can get inspiration to test your container locally and securely.